# URL Match RegEx Returns Always False

Tags: javascript, regex

This RegEx-literal function block always returns false when tested with a valid-format URL (which I've tested using [this](https://regex101.com/) site, and has come up as a true match).

```
function checkRegex (input) {
    var re = /^(https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([\da-z\.]{2,6})([\/w\.-]+)([\d\w\%\&\_\-\=\?]\/*)*$/i;
    return re.test(input);
}
```

The string I'm using as a test is: `https://google.com.net/ruefqij?random=true&rand2=false`

Comment: It returns true: http://jsfiddle.net/kweegkk7/

Comment: @stribizhev That's odd. I suppose it has something to do with the input not being... clean or something of the sort.

Answer (score 0):

Referenced the Object rather than the Object value. My mistake.